# How do left and right margin of pane's should be zero in dnn9

Tags: dotnetnuke

How do left and right margin of pane's  should be zero in dnn9, i do not want any right gap and left gap in my page as below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the entire site to be full-width, add this CSS somewhere

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

But if you only want the content pane, you need to add your own class to the container div holding the `main`

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container containerMain">
    <main role="main">

<style>
    .containerMain {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Or create/buy a skin and use that.